# Module '"react"' has no exported member 'SuspenseList'. TS2305

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

I'm trying to learn some of the new features in React 18, such as the `SuspenseList` and new `useId` hook, but I seem to be getting the same error over and over:

```
Module '"react"' has no exported member 'SuspenseList'.  TS2305
```

This is what my package.json looks like:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "history": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0-rc.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.5",
    "swr": "^1.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.27",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
```

I have no clue what to do at this point, as I've installed the RC version of React 18, which should be the latest according to the Working Group GitHub discussion board.

Comment: import { Suspense, SuspenseList } from "react";

Comment: yes all prerequistes are done and have worked fine until I'm trying to import the useId hook or SuspenseList from 'react'

Comment: So am I importing SuspenseList wrong? Since it says that 'react' doesn't have SuspenseList ?

Comment: That's a _TypeScript_ error - you have `@types/react` at v17, which won't include the new v18 types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone is still facing this issue Please install the latest version of @types/react
[More info in the attached npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react)
npm i @types/react

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error from the TypeScript compiler because, even though you've installed `react@next`, you're still using `@types/react@17`. `SuspenseList` does exist in the implementation, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Although there's no equivalent `@types/react@next` install, `@types/react` does include:

- `next.d.ts` (types which will definitely be in v18); and
- `experimental.d.ts` (types which are currently in experimental builds).

[The source code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/3d222f3227b8d0bce18bb0213f2c1f82858b28b5/types/react/experimental.d.ts#L1-L25) of the latter (as `SuspenseList` and the whole [concurrent mode API](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-reference.html) is still experimental) tells you how to use these types in a project:

> These are types for things that are present in the `experimental` builds of React but not yet
> on a stable build.
>
> Once they are promoted to stable they can just be moved to the main index file.
>
> To load the types declared here in an actual project, there are three
> ways. The easiest one, if your `tsconfig.json` already has a `"types"`
> array in the `"compilerOptions"` section, is to add `"react/experimental"` to
> the `"types"` array.
>
> Alternatively, a specific import syntax can to be used from a
> TypeScript file. This module does not exist in reality, which is why
> the `{}` is important:
>
> ```
> import {} from 'react/experimental'
> ```
>
> It is also possible to include it through a triple-slash reference:
>
> ```
> /// <reference types="react/experimental" />
> ```
>
> Either the import or the reference only needs to appear once, anywhere
> in the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborated answer.

I do find that I still have this error, having added "types": ["react-dom/next", "react/next"] to my tsconfig.tsx and 

if @types/react does include:

next.d.ts (types which will definitely be in v18); and
experimental.d.ts (types which are currently in experimental builds).

Then how come you're saying that my current types don't include these you mention? 

What do I type to get the latest types? As I have installed the latest types using a command I found, but that apparently is only for React17

Comment: @ClunkyKong `"react/next"`, if you look at what's actually in that file, _doesn't_ include `SuspenseList` - it's in `"react/experimental"`. Note the update to the answer.

Comment: ah thank you, had a few pieces fall together just now. Added the react/experimental thing to the types in tsconfig, but am now getting this error:

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `UserDetails


import is as follows:
import { Suspense, SuspenseList } from "react";

Comment: it is exported through  "export function UserDetails"

Comment: @ClunkyKong that seems like a separate error, it's happening at a completely different time (the one you report in the Q is from compile time, whereas that's at runtime). I'd suggest researching, and then if needed asking, it separately. That said, given that part of the API is experimental, maybe you need to install `react@experimental` too?

Comment: True it is a seperate error that has occured at runtime. 

I'm going to just see how much I can break it and take your advice. Thanks for the correct answer to the original Q :)

Comment: -after running npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental

it helped installing the experimental build of the experimental build and runs smooth now